# Creating a folder in `/var/run` when job is run as a non-privileged user

Tags: permissions, upstart

I have a few `upstart` scripts which are run as a non-priviledged user using [`setuid`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid). Pid files should be created in `/var/run/my-service`: `/var/run/my-service/v1.pid`, `/var/run/my-service/v2.pid` and so on.

The upstart scripts are created by a script, which also creates `/var/run/my-service` and sets the permissions, so everything works initially. But this folder will be gone after a reboot, and services will fail.

I tried this:

```
pre-start script
    [ -n $PID_DIR ] && [ ! -d $PID_DIR ] && mkdir $PID_DIR
    sudo chown my-user:my-group $PID_DIR
end script

setuid my-user
```

But it doesn't work:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
my-user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I guess it's because `setuid` affects all processes, even though it's after the `pre-start` and `sudo start my-service` was used.

How can I create the folder and set permissions, before the service is started ?

Comment: Disabling the `requiretty` flag in your `sudoers` file and/or adding the `NOPASSWD:` option should make that work... but I'm not saying that this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. sudo is not the right tool for anything regarding init systems. **please** avoid using it if possible.
2. setuid and setgid affect all stanzas of the upstart job, including the pre-start.
3. This can easily be worked around with the following job, my-service-prep.conf:

   ```
   start on starting my-service

   task

   PIDDIR=/var/run/my-service

   exec install -o my-user -g my-group -d $PIDDIR
   ```

With this, you can use setuid and setgid within the main upstart job and not face any permissions errors.

Comment: ended up storing the pid in the app folder; generally not a good idea but it works in my case.

Comment: The problem here (thanks to upstart's great design) is that if I need to have more than one process requiring the "/var/run/my-service" directory, then I need to add every job to the my-service-prep.conf file. I tried adding 'start on started my-service-prep' to the actual daemons I needed to spawn, but it did not work probably because my-service-prep is a task.